# Maintaing a lookup in OSB 11g?

Tags: oracle11g, esb, lookup, osb

I have to use a look-up feature to filter messages that are sent to a service. This is a sample input xml(simplified). Now, I need to use Tags `<ID>` and `<Name>` to look-up to a database table.

**My sample I/P:**

```
<Root>
 <A>
     <ID>100<ID>
     <Name>abc</Name>
 </A>
 <B>
 ...
 </B>
<Root>
```

I need to publish to the target service only when the input ID/Name are present in the look-up table.

How can I do this?
Should I go for DVM instead? Why?

Answer (score 0):

1. Save your xml as *.xq
2. Assign to variable with "Assign action"
3. $variable//ID = '100'

Answer (score 0):

You can use fn-bea:execute-sql() and in this you can pass the select statement to get the data from the database table. After retriving the data you can run if else condition to check and process accoringly.

Regards

Asutosh